Count number of permutations of numbers 1 to n where the k-th number is greater than the numbers on its left
For example, for $n=7, k=3$, the permutation $3245671$ is valid while $3214567$ isn’t.
My approach is as follows:
For index $k$, the only possible numbers to be placed in this index are $k,…,n$ since otherwise, there will be a number greater than the k-th number to it's left.
Suppose $i$ is one of the possibilities. Then there are $i-1$ numbers smaller than it. we have to choose $k-1$ from them to put on it’s left, and we care about their order, so: $\frac{(i-1)!}{(i-k)!}$. Then, we can shuffle the numbers to it’s right however we want: $(n-k)!$.
In total we get $\frac{(i-1)!}{(i-k)!}(n-k)!$. Then summing up for each possibly, we end up with: $$\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{(i-1)!}{(i-k)!}(n-k)!$$
I have 2 questions:

Is my approach and solutiom correct?
Is there a way to solve this question without summing?

Thanks!

Because of symmetry, the probability that the number in the $k$th position is the largest amongst first $k$, should be $\frac1k$.
Since there are $n!$ total number of permutation, and the probability of picking the correct one is $\frac1k$, the total number of  permutations where your condition is satisfied, is $\frac1k \times n!$.
At the same time, your summation also looks correct, as
$$
\sum_{i=k}^n \frac{(i-1)!(n-k)!}{(i-k)!}=
(n-k)!\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \frac{(j+k-1)!}{j!}=(n-k)!\cdot \frac{n!}{k(n-k)!}
$$
(you can prove that  $\sum_{j=0}^a\frac{(j+k-1)!}{j!}=\frac{(a+k)!}{a!k}$ by induction on $a$).

How from the conclusion you made you got to $\frac{n!}{k}$? Would you mind doing adding a bit more details about your thinking process? It would be greatly appreciated.

For any suffix of length $(n-k)$, there are $k!$ permutations with that suffix. Among these, there are $k!$ possible prefixes; they are the permutations of the elements not in the suffix.  Exactly $1/k$th of those (i.e. $k!/k$ of them) have the largest element in the kth position. There are $n!/k!$ such suffixes; summing over them gives $n!/k$ permutations with the largest of the first $k$ elements in the $k$th position.

@natitati, I clarified it a bit.

Thanks! I get it now.
